# Can we extend PDP to add external logic in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

We have a project specific requirement like a user must belong to a particular location to execute some action. We want to extend WSO2 PDP functionality where we may provide connection details to local db and provide conditions when a user can execute an action.

Planning to implement PEP-PDP using ESB and IS. Is there a way in PDP that can do this ?

Comment: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Writing+a+Custom+Policy+Info+Point might help you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Basically, you need to write a custom policy information point module. Please have a look at [1] on implementing a custom PIP (Policy Information Point) module

[1] http://xacmlinfo.org/2011/12/18/writing-jdbc-pip-module/